# JQuery Dialog not displayed in Fullscreen mode

Tags: jquery

I have a web which when in full screen mode should display a map filling the whole screen, I can do this no problem by putting the content in a div and requesting fullscreen for that div.

However I can't figure out how to get my JQuery dialogs to render when in fullscreen.  When JQuery initialises the dialogs it moves the dialog content div out into a new div it creates at the body level.  Is there anyway I can control where JQuery puts the dialog in the DOM so I can get it to render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  appendTo: "#someElem"
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#options

Comment: I did try that, however the content no longer appears in a dialog but displayed inline in the document, meaning you have to scroll down the page to view it rather than overlaying the page.

Comment: Ignore that, I've retried this in a test page and it works as I'd hope.  Now to figure out why it does not work on my page.